# Are there any Python libraries that are able to take input from keyboard and be able to understand what key I used

Tags: python, library, api, raspberry-pi

I'm making a robot car and I need a library like pygame that is able to recognize keyboard input and do a task (a created function, i.e. move forward, backward, left, right). But I need a module that doesnt bring up a GUI like pygame does and has a time delay function like pygame has. Basically everything that pygame has without the game creation part and the GUI part. Thanks.

Comment: Which keybindings do you need? The answer to your question in part depends on that. Would you personally count things made with curses as GUIs?

Answer (score 0):

The standard `termios` and `tty` library can be used.  See the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750536/python-input-single-character-without-enter